# Do Perforce Workspace edits apply instantaneously to the Depot?

Tags: perforce

I installed Perforce Server and P4V on my computer. In P4V, I clicked on an .ini file in my Workspace and edited it. Next, I go to the corresponding .ini file on my Depot and find out it has the edit too! I thought I was required to submit my changed .ini and make a new revision. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: You seem to be confused as to what the client is showing you.  It displays the state of your _local_ workspace.  If you made a change to that file, then yes, the client will indicate that it has been changed in its depot tree display.  However, until you submit it, there is no new revision on the server.

Answer (score 0):

In P4V, the `Depot` view and the `Workspace` view of the same file are both showing you the local copies of that file by default.   This can be a bit confusing.  The easiest way to tell that this is going on is that both files have the check mark next to them in P4V indicating that they are checked out for editing.

Until the file is submitted, it will not be stored on the server.  If you want to verify what changes have been made, use the `Diff against Have Revision` command (Tools menu or context menu) in order to see if there have been changes since the checkout and what they are.